What factors maintain chronic hemorrhoids?
Haemorrhoid sufferers are often told to eat more fruit/veg and check they are drinking enough water, then expect the problem to repair naturally. What factors might lead to regression of chronic piles that do not respond to those measures?
Factors directly causing hemorrhoids:

Constipation
Pregnancy
Over-use of steroid creams could possibly cause skin to be thinner, and tear more easily

Causes of constipation, which then leads to hemorrhoids:

Insufficient fibre intake
Insufficient water intake
Insufficient exercise
Stress and anxiety can cause IBS, including constipation
A significant percentage of those with autism have a strong link with constipation
Dairy allergies
Intolerance to processed sugar causes constipation (and migraine)

There are probably many more.

We do not /cannot give personal medical advice (see yellow box in sidebar), and evidence of research to answer your own question is required on this site. Without it, the question might be closed and eventually deleted. You provided info about formation of hemorrhoids, but no evidence of a search for treatment of refractory hemorhoids. Thanks.

That is OK, I have read the terms of this website, so I don't expect personal advice. I thought I had made my question very clear. But how do I provide evidence that I've spent the last decade on Google, and built up the above observations from 100 different sources over time?!

You do it -- for example -- by linking us to information that supports the two lists you provided.

Another cause of constipation is delay, e.g. not going frequently enough to the toilet.

Chronic hemorrhoids can persist despite standard dietary and hydration recommendations due to various factors. Understanding these factors is crucial for developing a comprehensive management plan. Here are several factors that can maintain chronic hemorrhoids and potential strategies for addressing them:
Factors Maintaining Chronic Hemorrhoids
Persistent Constipation or Diarrhea:
Management: Evaluate and treat underlying causes of chronic constipation or diarrhea, such as irritable bowel syndrome (IBS), dietary intolerances, or gastrointestinal disorders. Medications like stool softeners, fiber supplements, or antidiarrheal agents may be necessary.
Prolonged Straining:
Management: Educate patients on proper bowel habits, including not delaying bowel movements and avoiding excessive straining. Consider biofeedback therapy for those with pelvic floor dysfunction.
Inadequate Fiber and Fluid Intake:
Management: Ensure the patient is consuming adequate fiber (25-30 grams per day) and fluids (at least 8 glasses of water daily). Sometimes a dietitian’s guidance can help tailor dietary changes to individual needs.
Sedentary Lifestyle:
Management: Encourage regular physical activity, such as walking or other forms of exercise, to improve bowel function and reduce pressure on the rectal veins.
Obesity
Management: Weight loss through diet, exercise, and behavioral changes can reduce abdominal pressure and improve hemorrhoidal symptoms.
Pregnancy
Management: For pregnant women, focus on dietary modifications, hydration, and gentle exercise. Postpartum care should include continued attention to bowel habits and possibly medical or surgical intervention if hemorrhoids persist.
Chronic Cough or Heavy Lifting
Management: Treat chronic coughs and advise on proper lifting techniques to minimize intra-abdominal pressure.
Genetic Predisposition and Aging
Management: While genetic factors and aging cannot be changed, symptom management through lifestyle adjustments and medical treatments can help.
Inappropriate Use of Topical Treatments
Management: Advise proper use of topical treatments. Overuse of steroid creams can thin the skin and exacerbate issues. Use them only as directed by a healthcare provider.
Strategies for Managing Chronic Hemorrhoids
When standard measures fail, consider the following approaches
Behavioral and Lifestyle Modifications:
Toilet Habits: Establish regular bowel habits and avoid prolonged sitting on the toilet.
Exercise: Consistent exercise regimen to improve bowel motility and overall health.
Medical Treatments
Topical Treatments: Use appropriate non-steroidal topical treatments to reduce inflammation and pain.
Oral Medications: Flavonoid supplements (e.g., diosmin and hesperidin) can improve vein health and reduce symptoms.
Minimally Invasive Procedures
Rubber Band Ligation: Effective for internal hemorrhoids by cutting off blood supply, causing the hemorrhoid to shrink.
Sclerotherapy: Injection of a solution to shrink hemorrhoidal tissue.
Infrared Coagulation: Use of infrared light to cause coagulation and shrinking of hemorrhoids.
Surgical Options
Hemorrhoidectomy: Surgical removal of severe hemorrhoids, typically for those not responding to other treatments.
Stapled Hemorrhoidopexy: A procedure to reposition and fixate prolapsed hemorrhoidal tissue.
Alternative Therapies
Biofeedback Therapy: Particularly useful for patients with pelvic floor dysfunction contributing to straining and constipation.
Pelvic Floor Exercises: Strengthening the pelvic floor muscles can improve bowel control and reduce straining.
Conclusion
Chronic hemorrhoids can be maintained by a variety of factors beyond diet and hydration. Addressing these factors requires a comprehensive approach, including lifestyle changes, medical treatments, and potentially surgical interventions. Patients should be encouraged to seek medical advice for persistent symptoms to explore all available treatment options and improve their quality of life.

This appears to be a good answer and very complete, but the lack of supporting references makes it indistinguishable from an AI-generated answer. You'll need to [edit] it to add references.
